# Multiple arguments on aws glue start-job-run bash script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to execute an aws glue start-job-run command in a bash script where I need to pass multiple arguments in the --arguments parameter.

Here is an example of what I am expecting to do:

> aws glue start-job-run --job-name my-job --arguments "--key1=value1 --key2=value2"

I have tried various approaches, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works. Can someone help me understand how to properly format the arguments in this context?

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments to a Glue job are [a map](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/start-job-run.html).

As with any other AWS CLI command, you have a choice of [JSON syntax or shorthand syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-shorthand.html) for providing maps:

```bash
aws glue start-job-run --job-name my-job --arguments "key1=value1,key2=value2"
```

or

```bash
aws glue start-job-run --job-name my-job --arguments '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
```

(assuming a POSIX shell)

Comment: When i pass something like this "execution_date=2023-10-10,source_bucket=my_bucket,destination_bucket=dest_bucket" i get an error on parsing parameter '--arguments': Expected: '=', received '"' for input

Comment: @mictorgemas: are you running it on Windows?

Comment: Im running it in a Ubuntu EC2, the problem is that i needed to pass the arguments with '--', like --execution_date=2023-10-10 and so on. Ive tried passing just the string "--execution_date=2023-10-10" and  received the error --arguments: expected one argument. Without the '--' this one string worked, but my glue job failed as expects the "--execution_date", not "execution_date"

Comment: Good news, ive tried passing '{"--execution_date":"2023-10-10"}' and it passed!

Answer (score 0):

If you refer the [official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/start-job-run.html), , it says the arguments are map and below is the syntax to use it:

```
--arguments (map)
```

Shorthand Syntax:

```
KeyName1=string,KeyName2=string
```

Usage:

```
aws glue start-job-run --job-name my-job --arguments "KeyName1=value1,Keyname2=value2"
```